# I need to append logs to Auditlog.csv file in blob storage of DataLake Gen 2 from C#

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

```
var sa = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connection string);
var blobClient = sa.CreateCloudBlobClient();
string filename = "appendlogs.txt";
CloudAppendBlob appBlob1 = container.GetAppendBlobReference(filename);
if (!appBlob.Exists())
{
    appBlob.CreateOrReplace();
}
```

I am getting the error "The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict." while executing the line appBlob.CreateorReplace()

Please help how should I go about this and after creating this append blob how should I append it to my csv file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason you're getting this error is because your storage account has `Data Lake Gen2 (Hierarchical namespace)` enabled and `Append Blobs` are not supported there (at least as of now).

When I tried to create an append blob in such an account (using Node API BTW), I got the following error message:

```
{
    "name": "StorageError",
    "message": "Specified feature is not yet supported for hierarchical namespace accounts.\nRequestId:xxxx\nTime:2020-02-02T05:57:13.7882503Z",
    "code": "FeatureNotYetSupportedForHierarchicalNamespaceAccounts",
    "featurename": "Append Blobs",
    "statusCode": 409,
    "requestId": "xxxx"
}
```

I saw the same behavior on Azure Portal as well.